# shell script for geting mysql user grants details

Tags: linux, mysql, shell-scripting

I am trying to get mysql user grant details and echo it to out file

hari=`mysql -sN -e "show grants for mysqladm";`

echo $hari

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *prod_server_list.txt stage_server_list.txt user_grants1.txt user_grants.txt user_list_temp1.txt user_list_temp.txt* TO 'mysqladm'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*##############' WITH GRANT OPTION GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE `soxdv`.`chgpw` TO 'mysqladm'@'%' GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'mysqladm'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

It's getting .txt file name in the dir

Actual result must be as below

```
show grants;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for mysqladm@%                                                                                                              |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'mysqladm'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*#############################' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE `soxdv`.`chgpw` TO 'mysqladm'@'%'                                                                       |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'mysqladm'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION                                                                           |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

`*.*` is getting replaced with .txt file names

Kindly suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote what you echo or else echo will interpret wildcard with what it finds in the directory matching a pattern. It is called globbing and can be disabled.

```
box:[~/tmp/test]$ touch file.txt other.txt
box:[~/tmp/test]$ foo='*.txt'
box:[~/tmp/test]$ echo $foo
file.txt other.txt
nox:[~/tmp/test]$ echo '$foo'
$foo
box:[~/tmp/test]$ echo "$foo"
*.txt
box:[~/tmp/test]$ set -f 
box:[~/tmp/test]$ echo $foo
*.txt
```

- In example above you could see that echoing without quotes will
  result in globbing.
- Echo with single quotes will literally print
  what was inside quotes
- Echo with double quotes will print variable contents but will not glob
- Or you can disable globbing with set and freely echo without quotes.

I would recommend using double quotes or single quotes as necessary.